# PaaS API Warm-up call script

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I am fairly new to PaaS and I have been assigned a task to warm-up the api. we use caching, to speed the process up. However there is a initial hit on the first user first time they go to use the query.

I have a read about this for about 2 days now and I still cannot find the correct anwser.

**Code:**

```
    public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
        public override bool OnStart()
        {
            try
            {
                //do some work here
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine($"Exception during start {e}");
            }

            return base.OnStart();
        }


        public override void OnStop()
        {
            //if needed on stop method here
            base.OnStop();
        }  

    }
```

I have found [this](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/warming-up-kentico-in-azure-cloud-services) which helped alot and [this 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2013/05/14/running-scripts-from-a-windows-azure-roles-onstart-method/).

**My Question:**
How do i insure this is fired on deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a controller called WarmupController which called my `OnStart()`.
Then in the web.config I had to add the following.

```
<applicationInitialization >
  <add initializationPage="/api/warmup"/>
</applicationInitialization>
```

now when i deploy it runs this first.